# What is the difference between Variant.IsEmpty and Variant.IsNull?

Tags: c++builder

According to the help ([IsEmpty](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Variant.IsEmpty), [IsNull](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Variant.IsNull)), both return `true`

> if the VType field of the TVarData base class is varEmpty

I don't know if there is some subtle difference between both methods, or which one is the best/correct one to check to see if a Variant value has any data or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally *Null* indicates missing or unknown data. *Empty* indicates no data.

Think of a phone number field. If you don't know if someone has a telephone number at all, the field should be *Null*. If you *know* that someone doesn't have a telephone, then the field should be *Empty*.

Despite what the documentation says, `IsEmpty` checks for a value of `varEmpty` and `IsNull` checks for a value of `varNull`.

Comment: Yes, I understand the difference in the concepts, but I don't know if that translates to that functions in the RTL. At least for the definition in the help they would appear to be the same. How could you try the functions to get different values?

Comment: Ah, I see now the edit. I will try to get at example that shows the difference. Now... should one imply the other? I mean, if I field is Empty, for instance, would both return true? I remember having some issues in the past with this, when one of the functions would return something unexpected (for me, at least) but I'm not sure the specifics.

Comment: No, one does not imply the other. The VType field is *either* varEmpty *or* varNull. It can not be both.

Comment: @RodrigoGómez: just look at the RTL source code for yourself. In `{$BCB}\source\vcl\variant.cpp`, `Variant::IsNull()` calls `Variants::VarIsNull()`, and `Variant::IsEmpty()` calls `Variants::VarIsEmpty()`.  In `{$BCB}\source\rtl\sys\(System.)Variants.pas`, `VarIsNull()` returns whether `VType` is `varNull`, and `VarIsEmpty()` returns whether `VType` is `varEmpty`.